# IIS7 is it possible to get it to run a webpage every 5 mins?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, iis-7.5, timedelay

I have IIS7.5.  We currently have a weighted rating for entities on our website.  Calculating the weighted rating is extremely slow, to the point loading the homepage now takes more than 10 seconds to load.

To solve this, I'd like to store the weighting in the database with each entity, and have IIS run a script every 5-10 minutes that recalculates the weightings.

How do I go about doing this?  It would be easiest for me if it ran a webpage URL.

Comment: how to do that ? the background work ?

Comment: @Aristos yes how to make the server run it every 10 mins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To not use client, only server to continuously call this function, you can create a thread on the server to call the function that calculates it.

A better way to start the thread or timer is in the Global.asax, like this sample:

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    private Timer _timer;

    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int period = 1000 * 60 * 10; // 10 minutes
        _timer = new Timer(TimerCallback, null, 1000, period);
    }

    private void TimerCallback(object state)
    {
         // Do your stuff here
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks, this looks easiest.  I'm not too experienced with Global.asax, I would assume this would use the clients request to process though which would cause a long page load for one client every now and then?

Comment: I'm having a problem with this, the Timer() doesn't allow a constructor that takes 4 arguments.  I'm on ASP.net 4.0.  I've found this however (http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/129/Simple-task-Scheduling-using-Global.asax) which does a very similar thing which I might use

Comment: Use System.Threading.Timer. There is a System.Timers.Timer, but that have other usages.

Comment: Works a charm thank you :D  This page http://www.scirra.com/arcade/top now takes 330ms to open now as supposed to 7 seconds :D

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [`Cache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx) entry for this, set to expire 10 minutes in the future.

When you add the item, use a callback function for the `CacheItemRemovedCallback` parameter - in this callback function do your database work and re-add the expiring cache entry.

Other options include:

- Using one of the timer classes included in the BCL - there is a MSDN magazine article [describing and comparing the different ones](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx).
- Writing a windows service to do this.
- Using a [scheduled task](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler).

Windows service and schedules tasks still require you to have some way to communicate the results to IIS.

Comment: Thanks, not too keen on a cache though as this process is going to get slower and slower to run, I don't want a visitor every now and then to have a long page load.

Comment: @TomGullen - Not sure why that would have any bearing? The cache entry is only there as a "timer" using the web namespace - only used to fire the callback that will calculate stuff. It can contain junk (say a `null`) and not be used anywhere. Since it is using a callback, it will be using a separate thread and not have any impact on any of your users.

Comment: @TomGullen - It's a fair point. It is not the normal use of the cache.

Comment: I'm looking at the global.asax solution proposed here (http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/129/Simple-task-Scheduling-using-Global.asax) as it seems easiest/simplest to implement for me.  Is this a solution that will also not cost clients?  Or would I need to create a new thread?

Comment: @TomGullen - It will impact users. It fires on `session_start`. If the work is to be done at that point, the user will have to wait until it is finished. You could spin a thread to avoid this, but if you are not comfortable with that kind of thing, avoid the approach described.

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to use a Windows service for this rather than calling a web URL.

This can then run completely out-of-band in the background to perform calculations. Details on this are here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

A few advantages include:

- Your IIS process will not be affected, so your users will see no slowdown
- The service can be stopped or started independently of the Web site

However, you'll need to have reasonably full access to the server to install and run the service.

Comment: Thanks, will look into this now.

Comment: And of course, some way to communicate between the IIS process and the web service.

Comment: Possibly: it may be as simple as performing the calculations and writing them to a table somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something like this earlier and I had used windows scheduled tasks to call my script at specific intervals of time.

Answer (score -1):

A simple batch file with WGET or similar, and help from Scheduled Tasks will do it.

http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/

you can try this to test this idea:

```
wget http://localhost/filename.ashx
```